# Sentry object representations truncate in full view

Tags: python, exception, logging, truncate, sentry

We use sentry for our python code. We're experiencing a strange problem in which the representation of an object is being truncated when we try to inspect it in sentry. For example, when one goes to the "Exception" view and selects "Full", they are able to navigate around the stack trace. Within each segment of the stack trace sentry prints out the object's `__repr__`. Unfortunately, it seems to truncate longer representations. This is hugely problematic for us.

For those curious, we have already tried setting our `string_max_length` to 10,000 but it didn't appear to have an effect on these representations (although captureMessage now sends longer strings).

Comment: When you click on "View JSON", does the JSON representation have the object's full __repr__?

Comment: I don't see a "View JSON" link anywhere on the page. CTRL + F doesn't find it either.